# Laravel4.2 Query Problems between three tables

Tags: php, mysql, laravel-4, eloquent, laravel-5

Database Tables are

```
employers                        
id | username | password    

jobdetails
id | employer_id | title

empcompanies
id | employer_id | company_name
```

JobDetail.php // model

```
public function employer()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('Employer');
}
```

EmpCompany.php // model

```
public function employer()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('Employer');
}
```

Employer.php // model

```
public function empcompany()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('EmpCompany');
}

public function jobdetails()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany('JobDetail');
}
```

// Controller file

```
public function getApplyJobs($id)
{
    $jobs = JobDetail::where('id', '=', $id)->get();
    return View::make('home.apply')->with(compact('jobs'));
}
```

// view.blade.php file

```
@foreach($jobs as $job)
  @foreach($job->empcompany() as $emp)
    <td {{ $emp->company_name }}</td>
  @endforeach
@endforeach
```

// here $id is jobdetails id, it works and fetch all data from jobdetails table. My Question is- How to show company_name from empcompanies. I tried those codes but it does not show the company_name, it shows blank. I am using Laravel4.2 Pls Help..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I don't get it wrong this must be your answer:

in your  **JobDetails.php** //Model

```
public function empcompany()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('EmpCompany','employer_id','employer_id');
    }
```

and in your **EmpCompany.php** // model

```
public function jobdetails()
{
    return $this->hasMany('JobDetail','employer_id','employer_id');
}
```

// **Controller** File

```
$jobs = JobDetail::where('id','=',$id)->with('empcompany')->get();

return View::make('view')->with('jobs',$jobs);
```

and **view.blade.php**

```
@foreach($jobs as $job)
        <td>{{$job->empcompany->company_name}}</td>
@endforeach
```

Try this hope it works

Comment: @user267019 I did not get understand your question about employeer model? I did not change your code just modify your code.

Answer (score 0):

Your controller function should be

```
public function getApplyJobs($id)
{
$jobs = JobDetail::where('id', '=', $id)->with('empcompanies')->get();
return View::make('home.apply')->with(compact('jobs'));
}
```

and then iterate using

```
@foreach($jobs->empcompany as $emp)
<td {{ $emp->company_name }}</td>
@endforeach
```

also make sure that you have correct relations within the tables, I did not see your models as I believe these are fine

Comment: It retruns this error::
'BadMethodCallException' with message 'Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder::empcompanies()'
@Khan Shahrukh

Comment: It works @grhnkdlk..thanks.. but what about employer model, you does not specify that....Now I also edit my question of model part, pls look if now i want to show company name, what should i have to do????